# What does retain mean in the logging of WSJT-X 1.8.0?

Tags: ft8, wsjt-x

If you have automatic prompt for logging on WSJT-X, at the end, you get this dialog:

[image]

What does the "Retain" checkboxes do when you check them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When those boxes are checked, the values entered will be retained as the defaults for the next QSO to be logged.

Unchecked, the fields will revert to blank.